# Output in an A-Z and non A-Z characters in a List

Tags: php

I am trying to output any array to a directory list format.
A-Z is working, but I want to output words that don't begin with A-Z to the symbol #.

E.G. 1234, #qwerty, !qwerty, etc should be sorted to the # group.

```
<?php
$aTest = array('apple', 'pineapple', 'banana', 'kiwi', 'pear', 'strawberry', '1234', '#qwerty', '!qwerty');

$range = range('A','Z');
$range[] = "#";
$output = array();

foreach($range AS $letters){
    foreach($aTest AS $fruit){
        if(ucfirst($fruit[0]) == $letters){
            $output[$letters][] = ucfirst($fruit);
        }
    }
}

foreach($output AS $letter => $fruits){
    echo $letter . "<br/>--------<br/>\n";
    sort($fruits);
    foreach($fruits AS $indFruit){
        echo $indFruit . "<br/>\n";
    }
    echo "<br/>\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$output['#'] = array();

foreach($range as $letter){
    $output[$letter] = array();
}

foreach($aTest AS $fruit){
    $uc = ucfirst($fruit);
    if(array_search($uc[0], $range) === FALSE){
        $output['#'][] = $uc;
    } else {
        $output[$uc[0]][] = $uc;
    }
}
```

notice that I have removed outer loop, as you don't need it

Comment: Hi, Thank for the help. The letters are no longer sorted in an A-Z order. How can I get them like this: # A B C D etc

Answer (score 1):

You should reverse the order of the two `foreach` loops, use `break` and a temporary variable:

```
foreach($aTest as $fruit){
$temp = 1;
    foreach($range as $letters){
        if(ucfirst($fruit[0]) == $letters){
            $output[$letters][] = ucfirst($fruit);
            $temp = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if($temp){
        $output["#"][] = $fruit;
    }
}

ksort($output);
```

To avoid these complications, you may use only one `foreach` loop and the built-in PHP function [`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array):

```
foreach($aTest as $fruit){
$first = ucfirst($fruit[0]);
    if(in_array($first, $range)){
        $output[$first][] = ucfirst($fruit);
    }
    else{
        $output["#"][] = $fruit;
    }
}

ksort($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would categorize them first using [`ctype_alpha()`](http://php.net/ctype_alpha) and then sorting the result by the array key:

```
$output = array();

foreach ($aTest as $word) {
        $output[ctype_alpha($word[0]) ? strtoupper($word[0]) : '#'][] = $word;
}

ksort($output);
```